# Sharing information between threads using mutex vs messages

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, mfc

Edit : My question is still **unanswered** if anyone would like to take a shot at it

In my MFC C++ application, I share information between GUI thread and worker thread as shown in the following code. I have created a struct called inParams, which needs to be referenced from within both the main thread and the worker thread. Hence, I declare its members of std::atomic type, and in cases where atomic types dont exists, eg. for floats, I use a dedicated mutex. The Main Thread does operation *Foo* with this information and the worker thread does operation *Bar*. *Foo and Bar run concurrently*, and both can see changes to param1 and param2 as they are updated by user.

```
struct inParams{
    std::atomic_int param1;
    std::atomic_size_t param2;
    std::vector<customType> giantData;
    std::mutex giantDataMutex;
};

void myController::DoMainTask(){
    // Keep Handling GUI Events in this thread (main thread)
    // Create a Worker thread to do another task, I'll call it Bar
    SpawnWorkerThread()
}
void myController::SpawnWorkerThread(){
    std::thread t(&myController::tfunc, this);
    t.detach();
}
void myController::OnTimer(){  // say every 50 ms, just to simulate concurrency
    // When user changes param1 or param2, the changes affect here also
    Foo(inParams.param1, inParams.param2/* .. params list .. */);
}
void myController::tfunc(){
    while(1){
        // When user changes param1 or param2, the changes affect here also
        Bar(inParams.param1, inParams.param2, /* .. params list .. */); // 
    }
}

void myController::OnEventParam1(){ // User changed param1 in GUI
    inParams.param1 = GetValue( param1EditBox ); // GetValue gets value from Edit Box
}
void myController::OnEventParams2(){ // User changed param2 in GUI
    inParams.param2 = GetValue( param2EditBox );
}
```

My question is this - Is this an AntiPattern? Should I be using messages instead to share this information as opposed to sharing the params using mutex (by making them atomic)?

Do C++11 std::threads allow messaging or should I rely on PostThreadMessage API from WinAPI?

Comment: If you don't need microsecond-level response times, tying up a CPU to poll atomics for changes is probably overkill. I'd use a [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to notify the background thread to wakeup and look at the changed values. Also, `detach` is almost an anti-pattern. It's universally better to hold on to the `std::thread` and have some kind of shutdown protocol. (i.e., you probably need to stop the thread when `MyController` is destroyed)

Comment: @Casey 'It's universally better to hold on to the std::thread and have some kind of shutdown protocol' - no, it just isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You are using polling/timer to poll the shared variables. The advantage of using messages (PostMessage and PostThreadMessage) is it eliminates polling and lets the threads be event-driven.  It doesn't matter whether you pass data in the message or use the synchronized access that you have. Either way is fine, but polling is bad.

Comment: Actually, I use the timer only to make Foo and Bar concurrent. In my code, I use in fact a PostMessage for this. The Event Handlers are in the document class and the I do a PostMessage to the View class. 
I am more concerned that as the GiantData member of inParams is shared between two threads, will it lead to loss of efficiency or spaghetti code. I called it giantData, because it is several hundred megabytes in size.